# One job plist on Launchctl stop working with error: Service could not initialize: 17G5019: xpcproxy + 11472 [1524]

Tags: launchd, plist

I've a user plist job working on my iMac for latest month, and work fine. But today stop of work.

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/multimedia_search.plist
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/aria2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>multimedia_search</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/abkrim/Sites/multimedia/multimedia_search.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>~/multimedia_search.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>~/multimedia_search.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I put latest lines (StandardErrrorPath & StandardOutPath) for debug pourposes but service not write anything

If tunning of shell work fine

```bsh
/bin/sh /Users/abkrim/Sites/multimedia/multimedia_search.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /Users/abkrim/Sites/multimedia/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Error on system

```
Feb 18 10:42:57 iMac-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (multimedia_search[10324]): Service could not initialize: 17G5019: xpcproxy + 11472 [1524][1FC7BF6A-6296-382C-913A-4FF8915953DC]: 0xd
```

Apreciate help

Comment: Did you notice the <key>> (double > ) before StandardErrorPath? is it really there or is it a copy-paste error

Comment: Corrrected, uload, load and start and this not change any for question.

Comment: 1) why are you opening a whole new shell with the argument `/bin/sh`?  Secondly, what is your script doing?  If you have commands that are dependent on environment variables being set, you can be assured they're proably not being set in your new environemtn.   Finally, how are you loading this plist?  `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`?

Comment: Use /bin/sh because call to bash script (I've updated post with code). My script call with php artisan (Laravel) command for run a subcommand schelude:run. And most important this script run perfectly for 1 month. Finally, i write this `~/Library/LaunchAgents/multimedia_search.plist`. I think call daemon shuch user en `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: Beware the `~` you used in `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` are `bash` and some other shell metacharacter. It is a standard character within a `plist` file.

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Just put a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your script.  I'm now confused by your statement "it run perfectly for 1 month."   Are you saying it worked before and now stopped or it doesn't work at all?

Comment: Yes. I say, I confirm, that this plist working for last month and it's run every minute queue in my local Laravel App, and process 750000 images (queue run every minute for process almost 40 images)